# What is the correct way to remove RSA key-pair entirely from my SSH configuration?

Tags: encryption, openssh

Suppose these two operating systems and SSH software:

- GNU/Linux Debian 9.3 with OpenSSH version `1:7.4p1-10+deb9u2`
- Linux Mint 18.3 with OpenSSH version `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4`

And I want to switch away from [`rsa`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) completely to the benefits of curve [`ed25519`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519).

---

The question is, after I generate [`ed25519`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) on both systems with:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

And copy the public keys with `ssh-copy-id`, shall I delete the [`rsa`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) key-pair with `rm` or is that a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, deleting the key pair is fine. All you have to do is to delete your public key from the server. However, you don't remove it with `rm`; you delete the relevant lines from the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Check first that you can log in with your new key pair!

For cleanliness, I'd also suggest you to remove your private key from the client machine, although that would make no difference.